# $U(\mathbb{C}^n)$, $SU(\mathbb{C}^n)$ connected subsets of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

As the title suggests, is $U(\mathbb{C}^n)$ a connected subset of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$? How about $SU(\mathbb{C}^n)$?

Comment: Have you tried a simplified version of the problem, as when $n$ is small?

Comment: Use the fact that unitary matrices are diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both of those are connected (in fact, path-connected) subsets of $M_n$.

It is notable that they are not generally simply-connected.